# Sharepoint access public folder via REST API without authentication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api

Is it possible to access a folder, which I made publicly accessible via link, from the SharePoint REST API (without beeing authenticated)?

Currently when I try to access:
`https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Freigegebene%20Dokumente')/Folders`
I get a UnauthorizedAccessException

However when I navigate to the shared link once (without beeing authenticated). It seems like some cookies get set and then the REST request works as well!

How can I assure the REST request works, without the need to first access the shared link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is not possible to access public folders/files via the REST API.

To access the files and folders I solved this by [registering an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-register-app) with the Microsoft Identity platform and using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) to access the files and folders in the SharePoint site.